# Gun.js not responsive on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, gun, no-response

After successfully running Gun.js, creating a user, and loging in on the browser, I tried to use it on NodeJS and react native. However, I was unable to get it running, in my case, it just simply froze and no output was being printed.

Code:
Browser:

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gun/gun.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gun/sea.js"></script>
<script>
const gun = Gun();
gun.user().create("John,"Johnsmith123",(ack)=>{console.log(ack)});
 gun.user().auth("John","Johnsmith123",(ack)=>{console.log(ack)});
</script>
</html>
```

Node:

```js
const Gun = require("gun");
require("gun/sea");

const gun = Gun();
gun.user().create("John,"Johnsmith123",(ack)=>{console.log(ack)});
 gun.user().auth("John","Johnsmith123",(ack)=>{console.log(ack)});

// No response
```

Logs:

```
Hello wonderful person! :) Thanks for using GUN, please ask for help on http://chat.gun.eco if anything takes you longer than 5min to figure out!
$
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!
Alvin.